# ¿Cómo recorrer letra por letra en un string y verificar si se repiten?

Tags: python, string, bucles

Estoy practicando cadenas en Python y tengo muchas dudas en la forma de recorrer una palabra y verificar que sus letras no se repitan (por ejemplo). Mi idea fue recorrer la cadena de esta manera:

```
palabra = "abcdefghijkl"

letra_repetida = False

for i in range(0, len(palabra)):

    if palabra[i] == palabra[i + 1]:

        letra_repetida = True
```

El problema es que esto lógicamente esta mal ya que me salgo del rango de la palabra al hacer "palabra[i + 1]"

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto tipo "Bubble Sort" pero en letras? Gracias

Comment: La pregunta está incompleta! "recorrer una palabra y verificar que sus letras no se repitan" te faltó consecutivamente que es distinto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En un comentario dijiste:

> Mi idea era buscar si se repiten las letras de tal manera que la siguiente no sea la misma ¿a que me refiero? Si yo tengo la cadena = "abcdde" me gustaría aprender la forma de evaluarlas de esta manera: primero evaluó la "a" y "b" ¿son iguales? No, sigue el código. Segundo: "b" y "c" ¿son iguales? No, sigue el código. Tercero: "c" y "d" ¿son iguales? No, sigue el código. Cuarto: "d" y "d" ¿son iguales? Si. Y ahí cortaría finalizaría el código.

Para ese caso tu ciclo `for` esta más que bien, pero para evitar el error `index out of range` no vamos a iterar en la longitud del string sino en `len(str)-1`.

```
palabra = "abcdde"
for i in range(len(palabra)-1):
    if palabra[i] == palabra[i + 1]:
        print("la letra se repite")
        break #paramos el ciclo
```

El `for` al momento de encontrar una palabra repetidas parará. Si quieres saber cuantas veces se repite un carácter las otras respuestas te pueden ayudar.

Comment: Lo siento por demorar en en la respuesta, me entretuve jugando >_<

Comment: partamos de la base que el planteo de la pregunta entonces está mal, solo quiere saber si se repiten consecutivamente, no si se repiten en la cadena y @Crhistian hay un error tipográfico en como detener el bucle.

Comment: @tincopasan cualquier comentario a cerca del planteo de la pregunta se lo debes hacer al AP y gracias por avisarme del error. :D

Answer (score 3):

Es bien simple. Basta con evaluar

```
len(palabra) != len(set(palabra))
```

Ahi comparamos el número total de letras (dado por `len`) contra el número de letras únicas. La función `set` convierte la palabra en un conjunto de letras sin repeticiones, y el `len` del `set` me da su número de elementos.

Si ambos valores coinciden, no hay repeticiones.

**Demo**

```
palabra = "abcdefgahijkl"
if len(palabra) != len(set(palabra)):
    print("letras repetidas")
else:
    print("todas distintas")
```

Comment: Es excelente para saber si no hay repeticiones de palabras, pero en caso quiera saber cuantas veces se repite no serviría de mucho y tendría que implementar un ciclo `for`

Comment: Lo publicado es la respuesta a la pregunta del OP. Si tienes una pregunta distinta, puedes publicarla para analizarla.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que hay mejores forma de hacerlo:
Supongamos que tenemos la cadena "Hola, mundo" y queremos saber si la letra/vocal "o" se repite, entonces hago esto:

```
cadena = "Hola, mundo"
ocurrencias = cadena.count("o")
print(ocurrencias)
```

**salida**

```
>> 2
```

---

Entonces adaptado a tu código sería:

```
letra_repetida = false
cadena = "Hola, mundo"
ocurrencias = cadena.count("o")
if ocurrencias > 1:
 letra_repetida = True
 print("Se ha encontrado repetición")
```

**salida**

```
>>Se ha encontrado repetición
```

---

Entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer (Con un poco de esteroides ;D)

Éxitos!

Answer (score 2):

La verdad es que no se si hay buscador y supongo que esta pregunta puede estar repetida, pero lo haría basicamnte así:

```
palabra = "abcdefghijklazb"
letras={}
letras_repetidas=''
```

Agregué letras solo para que haya repeticiones y creo un diccionario vacío

```
for letra in palabra:
    if letras.get(letra):
        letras_repetidas+= letra
    else:
        letras[letra] = True
        
print(letras_repetidas)
```

recorremos la cadena y verificamos si se puede obtener el valor de la letra en el diccionario si es así la agrego a la cadena vacia de letras repetidas
sino la agrego al diccionario.

Con respeto a "Bubble Sort" no tiene sentido es solo una forma de ordenamiento y salvo que tengas que practicar, python ya trae funciones de ordenamiento.